# I need to solve this little riddle. It has description pyphp64

Tags: python

*I got this but I don't know what I need to do with that:*

**Jycuam9pbihbY2hyKG9yZChpKV44MikgZm9yIGkgaW4gJyI9XCcoOzhydCE9XCcgMTcnXSk=**

*it has description - pyphp64. 
I think that was a Code64 and when I decode that i got:*

**''.join([chr(ord(i)^82) for i in '"=\'(;8rt!=\' 17'])**

Comment: it seems to be some legit python code, you can execute it in python and see what comes out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`''.join([chr(ord(i)^82) for i in '"=\'(;8rt!=\' 17'])` would be what you have to run next. `.join()` append strings to a string from a list, and the list contains the result of `chr(ord(i)^82) for i in '"=\'(;8rt!=\' 17'`. When you run this, it gives the output `pouzij &source` as a string. I would look there next.

Comment: Nice, it is saying to use &source but i dont know how to use that &source